# How to maximize the following integral?

Tags: integration

Suppose $f : [1,3]\to \mathbb R$ such that $-1\leq f(x)\leq 1, x\in [1,3]$, and
$$\int _1^3 f(x)\mathrm{d}x = 0. $$
Determine the largest possible value of
$$\int _1^3 \frac{f(x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x. $$

I have found that largest value is $\log3$. But what is the role of that integration which is given to be zero. Is there any other way to solve.

Comment: How could you find the answer if you didn't use the fact that $\int_1^3 f(x) dx = 0$? In addition, can you type your question up in MathJax?

Comment: Using the upper bound of $f$. The integration is boinded above by $\int\limits_{1}^{3}\frac{1}{x}dx=\log 3$

Comment: @J.Doe But if $f(x)=1$ then $\int_1^3 f(x)\ \mathsf dx = 2\ne0$.

Comment: ok. correct. then how we can do?

Comment: @Math1000 You don't have to take $f = 1$. The argument shows that we can't go higher than $\log 3$ as long as $-1\leq f\leq 1$.

Comment: yeah .. I thought like that. but then what can be the use of that integration which is given to be zero.

Comment: I am considering starting a bounty if no progress is made on proving that $\ln 4/3$ is the greatest possible value.

Answer (score 2):

Define $f(x)$ to be $1$ when $1 ≤ x < 2$ and $-1$ when $2 ≤ x ≤ 3$.

Then the integral is equal to:

$$\int_1^2 \frac{f(x)}{x} \mathrm d x + \int_2^3 \frac{f(x)}{x} \mathrm d x$$ 
$$= \int_1^2 \frac{1}{x} \mathrm d x + \int_2^3 \frac{-1}{x} \mathrm d x$$
$$= [\ln x]_1^2 + [-\ln x]_2^3$$
$$= (\ln 2 - \ln 1) + (- \ln 3 + \ln 2)$$
$$=  \ln 4 - \ln 3 = \ln \left( \frac{4}{3} \right)$$

This is most likely the function that gives the greatest value. For constant functions, adjusting where the function 'breaks', and the number in the constant function does not seem to give an answer greater than this.

The requirement that $\int_1^3 f(x) \mathrm d x = 0$ is to make sure that $f(x)$ cannot be equal to $1$ within the interval. Otherwise you can use the argument that the integral is bounded above by $\int_1^3 \ln x \ \mathrm d x = \ln 3$.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: That's indeed the correct solution. It's obvious that the solution is decreasing. To show that the solution must be plus or minus one everywhere, note that you could improve the objective while keeping the integral constraint by subtracting from the right and adding to the left in a neighborhood where the function is strictly in between the bounds.

Comment: @Bananach how to prove rigorously that $\ln(4/3)$ is the maximum?

Comment: This is what I thought of posting, but I don't know how to prove that it is indeed the maximum.

Comment: @Szeto Claim A: For any non-decreasing function there is a decreasing function with higher objective  Proof A: Switch around non decreasing bits of the function. Claim B: For any function that has some values strictly in between 1 and -1 there is a function with values 1 and -1 only with higher objective. Proof B: see above. Claim C: the best function that is 1 first and then -1 is the function given in this answer. Proof C: Trivial.

Comment: @Bananach what is ‘objective’?

Comment: @Szeto the integral we're trying to maximize